# Dynamic button layout android

Tags: android

I'm trying to build buttons via xml layout, depending on parameters grabbed from the server (x/y coords mostly). Best I got so far requires me to update the app each time I want a new layout, but I'm trying to find a more efficient way. So the number of actual buttons and their position is relative to the data grabbed from the database. How would I go on about doing this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? (BTW, the fact that you are setting your UI components by coords returned by a WS blows my mind.)

Comment: if the number of possible layouts is limited, you can prepare all the possible layouts (say choice_1.xml, choice_2.xml, ...) in advance and load them dynamically. Else, you have to add the buttons programmatically.

Comment: Is it just buttons and nothing else? Does the client know anything about the layout? For example if you didn't have a server situation, would you make an AbsoluteLayout and place the buttons in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move buttons at run-time, use an empty `<View />` whose size is set programmatically; the buttons will be, say, below it. (Works both for `<LinearLayout ...>` and `<RelativeLayout ...>`). Use `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` and *getMeasuredWidth()* to get the actual sizes.

Note that you can do really a lot by just making some buttons/views invisible (`someView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`, the other two possible values are `View.VISIBLE` and `View.INVISIBLE`). If possible, you should prefer this approach because it allows you to have a more or less sane layout under any circumstances.